# Android application design choice

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I want to create an application that opens a connection to another device in LAN and send /receive request/responses. Its like a [GMote](http://www.gmote.org/) application.

I am thinking about creating a service in which I create the connection. My activity will have to send/receive using this service. The connection will remain open as long as the service is running or the devices are in LAN range.

Can there be any performance issue with such approach, like any cost of communication between activity and service? Some of the actions in my application can send message after 200 millisec delays for 2-4 seconds.

The other way is to create the connection in activity, but then I have to create it every time my activity starts. The OS can terminate the activity any time if it is not in `focus`.

Which approach is best suited for such used application?

Comment: 5-10 times a day is in my opinion not frequently. How long will 1 usage take? The delay between an Activity and Service depends how fast an Intent is handled by the Service.

Comment: In terms of web services ussage, 5-10 times a day is not frequently. Are you talking of Android applications specific performances issues or service performance issues? Or both? For your case it should be better to create a connection with a timeout of a few seconds (4-5), not creating one for each activity. But it depends if the service is used only for your Android application or for others also.

Comment: Its like a GMote application (remote control). I cannot quantify time for 1 usage, it can be random, as such the usage per day is also random. The communication data would be just control messages (short length).

Comment: The reason I asked the performance question is because I am thinking that there could be inter-process communication involved that can mean that the intent is serialized and sent between activity and service.

Comment: The service would be used only by that application